# How to structure large pyqt5 GUI without subclassing QThread and using QPushButtons to do long-running tasks

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread, qpushbutton

I'm looking at creating a program with a PyQt5 GUI. The program will start with a UI with numerous buttons. These buttons will be used to open other programs/completed long running tasks. I know I need to use QThread, but I am unsure how to structure the programs so that it scales properly.

I've been at this for ages and have read numerous posts/tutorials. Most lean down the subclassing route. In the past, I have managed to create a working program subclassing QThread, but I have since read that this metholodogy is not preferred.

I have a feeling I should be creating a generic worker and passing in a function with *args and **kwargs, but that is not in my skillset yet.

I originally created a thread for each button during the GUI init, but that seemed like it was going to get out of hand quickly.

I am currently at the stage of creating a thread under the slot connected to the button.clicked signal. I am not sure if I then have to have a worker for each button or if I can/should make a generic worker and pass in a function. Note: I have tried to do this but have not been able to do it.

```
#Import standard modules
import sys

#Import third-party modles
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class Worker(QObject):

    #Custom signals?? or built-in QThread signals?
    started = pyqtSignal()    
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.started.emit()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def do_something(self):
            for _ in range(3):
                print('Threading...')
                QThread.sleep(1)
            self.finished.emit()

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        #Create GUI
        self.centralWidget  = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget )  
        self.vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle('QThread Test')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 50)
        self.button1=QPushButton("Task 1", self, clicked=self._task1_clicked)
        self.button2=QPushButton("Task 2", self, clicked=self._task2_clicked)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.vertical_layout.addStretch()

    def _task1_clicked(self):
        print('task1 clicked')

        #Create the worker
        self.my_worker = Worker()          

        #Create thread; needs to be done before connecting signals/slots
        self.task1_thread = QThread()

        #Move the worker to the thread
        self.my_worker.moveToThread(self.task1_thread)        

        #Connect worker and thread signals to slots
        self.task1_thread.started.connect(self._thread_started)
        self.task1_thread.started.connect(self.my_worker.do_something)
        self.my_worker.finished.connect(self._thread_finished) 

        #Start thread
        self.task1_thread.start() 

    def _task2_clicked(self):
        print('task2 clicked')

    def _thread_started(self):
        print('thread started')

    def _thread_finished(self):
        print('thread finished')
        self.my_worker.isRunning = False
        self.task1_thread.quit()
        self.task1_thread.wait()
        print('The thread is running: ' + str(self.task1_thread.isRunning()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Window()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The above seems to work, but I feel like I have stumbled on to it and it is not the correct way of doing this. I do not want this to be my 'go-to' method if it is completely wrong. I'd like to be able to generate more complicated (more buttons doing things) programs compared to a one button/one task program.

In addition, I can't seem to get the QThread started and finished signals to fire without basically making them custom built signals. This is one reason I think I am going about this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class AsyncTask(QtCore.QThread):
    taskDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)
    def __init__(self, *, task, callback=None, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.task = task
        if callback != None:
            self.taskDone.connect(callback)
        if callback == None:
            callback = self.callback
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        try:
            result = self.task()
            print(result)
            self.taskDone.emit(result)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    def callback(self):
        print('callback')
```

Please try code above, call like this:
    AsyncTask(task=yourTaskFunction, callback=yourCallbackFunction)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I've used some of your ideas in your response and tried to see if I can work it into my program. You have, however, subclassed QThread; how would you go about solving this without subclassing it? Do large scale projects have separate Worker(QObjects) for each long-running task or would a single worker have as many long-running tasks under separate functions?

Comment: Hi McRae, maybe I'm not completely understood your problem. I think single worker or multiple workers depends on your business requirements. You can put related tasks or functions in one worker, and multiple workers handle tasks with different types or categories.